# Adding comment to a column using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to create column comments when creating a table using sequelize?

The document [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html) only says that you can add a comment to a table. But how can I add a comment to each column?

The following code doesn't work.

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT,
  comment: "This is a comment"
})
```

The way I check whether column comment is successfully added or not is executing `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM table_name`.

Here's the version of my mysql server:

```
innodb_version  5.7.18
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions  
tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1
version 5.7.18
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
```

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3553

I think this issue has given me the answer. For now, this feature is not supported.

Comment: The `here` link is broken – goes to a 404 page

Comment: you define a model/table and add a column named comment.

Answer (score 3):

Currently it's works for me

```
  createdDate: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    comment: 'UNIX TIMESTAMP'
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

you should do this,

```js
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT,
  
},{
  comment: "This is a comment"
})
```

[Finally you can specify a comment for the table in MySQL and PG](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration)

you can move to official website, and see

Comment: But it's not a comment to column.

Comment: Instead confusing readers, please remove answer

Comment: Your link goes to a 4040